# UITabBarController selectedIndex lagging by one click

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have been using the tabBarController selectedIndex to determine whether a navigation bar should be displayed. Everything was working fine for most of today, but now this line of code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

is giving the last selected index rather than the currently selected index. I am running this line of code in viewWillAppear to make sure that a particular view which has index 1 in the tabBarController will not show its navigation bar on its first view.

But it's reporting 1 click behind. For example, when I click on the 2nd index and then the 1st index, my last click shows up as having selected the view controller at index 2 even though I have just clicked on the view controller with index 1. Also, the selectedIndex is always listed correctly the first time I click on any view controller but never correct after the first time it is viewed via the tabBarController.

I've looked over the tabBarController class reference, but it seems like this selectedIndex property should be straightforward. What am I  missing?

Comment: Use dispatch_once or something or use tabbar delegate

Comment: @Andy thanks for your comments but dispatch_once will not work because I am reusing view controllers across different tabBar indices. I looked at the tabbar delegate, but I don't see how/why that's how to fix this selectedIndex lag. Can you clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am reusing view controllers across different tabBar indices"? Explain your controller setup.

Comment: @rdelmar I am loading the same subclassed UIViewController both as a viewController directly in the tabBar array of view controllers and also as a root view controller and also as a popped view controller in a navigation controller that is in the array of tabBar view controllers.

Comment: The problem is putting the code in viewWillAppear -- the value of selectedIndex hasn't been changed at that point (it is by the time viewDidAppear is called).

Comment: @rdelmar You are right - that did the trick. However I don't understand why it worked all day in that case? Also if I do it this way I am left with a giant black hole when I hide the navigation bar that wasn't originally there...

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have it in viewDidAppear before, and then changed it at some point?

Comment: @rdelmar Quite sure because I wasn't using viewDidAppear until your suggestion just now. It was't in my code at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that viewWillAppear is called before the index has actually changed.
First, tabBarController shouldSelectViewController -> viewWillAppear -> tabBarController didSelectViewController -> viewDidAppear.
I have a similar setup where I reuse ViewControllers across different tabBar indices. I did not want to check for the selectedIndex in the viewDidAppear even though that would fix the problem.
What I did to fix the problem was to go by a tag. Both ViewControllers have different UINavigationController and I set the tag of one navBar to 1. Every time I need to know which Controller is active I now check for the tag.